# DayView using collection View

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have made a day view using a collection view. What I want to achieve is that how to show the progressive timings in which each row  will be separated from the previous row by a regular time interval. Also the start time and End time is also variable.

Consider a scenario:

Start time is 08:00 AM and end time is 05:00 PM 
The time difference between each row is 15 minutes.

so that it looks something like this
08:00 AM
08:15 AM
08:30 AM
08:45 AM
09:00 AM
09:15 AM 
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
and so on up to 05:00 PM
Also the cell should not use reuse the time on scrolling upwards and downwards again and again.
Can anybody help me with this issue to build a dynamic logic which is compatible with every time range and slot difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to add the rows as time elapse?

Comment: yes somewhat like that.. like the day view in the calendars

Comment: can anybody please respond to this?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147224/display-stopwatch-timer-in-uitableviewcell-dynamically

Comment: I am not looking for this. What I need is to show the time slots in each row separated by a fixed time interval. For example first row shows 08:00 AM and then the second one shows 08:15 AM.